# How do I overwrite the master branch of a git repository with an unrelated branch from a different repository?

Tags: git, github

I recently switched computers and in the process updated some software tools to their latest versions. I had a project (version-controlled in git, with a lot of history) that I had been building up with the old software, that would not build anymore once I had migrated. With the new software, I started a fresh repo and I took the time to manually change the same settings and configurations that constituted most of the old repo's history, but I did so in a completely new repository that thus has no commit history.

I now have a working master branch with the updated software in the 'newer' repo, but would like to add this as a commit on top of the existing repository with all its history. There are files that are common between both repos, but both also now have files that are unique to each of them after the software migration.

**What I have:**

```
Repo 1:
... A - B - C - D
                ^
              master
Repo 2:
E - F
    ^
  master
```

**What I would like to do:**

```
A - B - C - D - E - F
                    ^
                  master

or even this would work:

A - B - C - D - F
                ^
              master
```

**How can I overwrite the master branch from a separate repo without losing history?**

Answer (score 0):

You can't (quite) get what you want: commit `E` already exists and is a *root commit*, i.e., has no parent.  Commit `F` already exists and has commit `E` as its lone parent.

You easily can get what you want, as long as you change what you want slightly to be:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- origin/master
          \
           E'-F'   <-- master

E--F   <-- repo2/master
```

where commit `E'` has the same *snapshot* as commit `E`, but has, as its parent, commit `D`, and commit `F'` has the same *snapshot* as commit `F`, but has, as its parent, commit `E'`.

To get this:

1. Clone the original repository.
2. Add the URL for `repo2`, e..g, `git remote add repo2 *url`.
3. Run `git fetch` to obtain commits `E--F`.
4. Find the hash ID of commit `E` (e.g., `git log --max-parents=0 repo2/master`).
5. Use `git replace --graft` to make an `E'` whose parent is `D`, e.g., `git replace --graft <hash from step 4> origin/master` (if I remember the syntax right off-hand).
6. Verify that what you have looks right (e.g., `git log --graph`, `gitk`, whatever you like to use to view the graph).
7. Run `git filter-branch` as a no-op filter, or `git filter-repo` similarly, to "cement the graft into place".

Ideally, since commits `A-B-C-D` are unchanged (bit for bit identical to the originals) they still have the original hash IDs, so that you can now `git push origin master`.